# HTML5 Canvas erase lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm not familiar with jquery and canvas, I would like to make an eraser (like the eraser tool in photoshops or paint) , erases some lines in my canvas.

> Marker - triggers to start draw
>   Reset - clears the canvas
>    Eraser - erases unnecessary lines/sketch (What i would like to do)

Here's the code so far I got using different sources, I would like to include **ERASER**

```js
$(function() {
    $.each(['#f00', '#ff0', '#0f0'], function() {
    
      $('#colors_demo').append("<a href='#colors_sketch' data-color='" + this + "' style='width: 30px;height: 30px;display:inline-block; background: " + this + ";'></a> ");
    });
    $('#colors_sketch').sketch();
    $('#colors_sketch').sketch({defaultColor: "#ff0"});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js"></script>

<div id="colors_demo" class="tools">
  
</div>
<div class="tools">
  <a href="#colors_sketch" data-tool="marker">Marker</a>
  <a href="#colors_sketch" data-tool="eraser">Eraser</a>
</div>
<canvas id="colors_sketch" width="800" height="300"></canvas>
```

I was having difficulty to search online since it just shows **reset** or **undo** 
Hope somebody can help me out.
THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: For transparent background, you would normally use `globalCompositeOperation` 'destination-out'. But the lib you are using makes it impossible because they do record all the points coordinates and redraw the whole paths every time. So you're stuck with an opaque bg solution, or to rewriting the drawing app yourself (it's not so hard, and there are a lot of examples showing you how to do it in here)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you get around and use the background color as an eraser tool

Below a sample sniipet :

```js
$(function() {
    $.each(['#f00', '#ff0', '#0f0'], function() {
    
      $('#colors_demo').append("<a href='#colors_sketch' data-color='" + this + "' style='width: 30px;height: 30px;display:inline-block; background: " + this + ";'></a> ");
    });
    var color = getBackground($('#colors_sketch'));
    //console.log(color);
    $("#eraser").attr('data-color',color);
    $('#colors_sketch').sketch();
    $('#colors_sketch').sketch({defaultColor: "#ff0"});
});

function getBackground(jqueryElement) {
  var color = jqueryElement.css("backgroundColor");
  if(color == "transparent"){
    color = jqueryElement.parent().css("backgroundColor") == "transparent" ? "#fff" : jqueryElement.parent().css("backgroundColor");
    //alert(color)
  }
  return hexc(color);
}

function hexc(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    color = '#' + parts.join('');

    return color;
}
```

```css
#colors_sketch {
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:#999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js"></script>

<div id="colors_demo" class="tools">
  
</div>
<div class="tools">
  <a href="#colors_sketch" data-tool="marker">Marker</a>
  <a id="eraser" href='#colors_sketch' data-color=''>Eraser</a>
  <a href="#colors_sketch" data-tool="eraser">Clear</a>
</div>
<canvas id="colors_sketch" width="800" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes , seems making its own js draw code would be better rather than using sketch !

Comment: @DownCrow does this swwet your demand , if so mark the quest as resolved thnx :D